# 'Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

When adding this part of my code to my Startup.cs class

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), false)
                .Build();

            // Make the loaded config available via dependency injection
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);
```

I got this error *System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find an Azure Storage connection string to use for this binding.'* in WebJobsServiceCollectionExtensions.cs class i also have AzureWebJobsStorage variable in my local.settings.json.

Comment: Share the detailed error stack that you're getting (with error code)...

Answer (score 0):

Define your connection string in **local.settings.json.**

```
{
   AzureWebJobsStorage={YOURCONNNECTIONSTRINGHERE)
}
```

**Azure Key Vault**

In **Startup.cs** class , add the Json file path

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```